# AMD_pinned_memory - Syncing transfer into a texture

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I just read the following [presentation](http://developer.amd.com/afds/assets/presentations/2116_final.pdf) about AMD_pinned_memory.

However I have a question regarding to syncing the transfers.

When copying the data from a buffer to a texture they show the following example (on pages 12):

*Copy data from a buffer into a texture*

```
// Bind buffer as unpack buffer to copy data into a texture object
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_pBuffer[m_uiBufferIdx]);
// Copy pinned memory to texture
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, m_uiTexWidth, m_uiTexHeight, m_nExtFormat, m_nType, NULL);
// Insert Sync object to check for completion
m_UnPackFence= glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
```

When and how do I wait for the `m_UnPackFence`? Do I need to call `glClientWaitSync` or `glWaitSync` just before using the texture or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of your other question about keeping data written to a mapped buffer around. I think you completely misunderstood the whole idea of mapping buffers in OpenGL. Pinned memory isn't going to help you either, because even with the memory pinned you need to synchonize with OpenGL (read the last sentence on page 11 of the presentation you linked). Last but not least pinned memory will only work performant on CPU/GPU combinations like AMD Fusion. On regular systems you've got the PCI-E bottleneck inbetween.

Regarding your original problem. I think you completely misunderstand what glMapBuffer does. It maps some part of GPU memory into your applications address space. This is not like regular system memory. In fact it's a good idea to keep a copy of the original data around. In fact reading from a mapped buffer will have quite bad performance, unless the OpenGL driver makes a copy of the data for you to read. Think about it: Everytime you map that buffer, the data has to be copied from the GPU.

The solution to your problem is simple: Just keep a copy of your data. This is not a bottleneck. And maybe `glBufferSubData` may be even better suited for you.

Comment: "you need to synchonize with OpenGL (read the last sentence on page 11", I'm aware of that, how does that change anything? I can still read from the data on the cpu while it is synchronizing? "Last but not least pinned memory will only work performant on CPU/GPU combinations like AMD Fusion." doesn't CUDA recommend using pinned memory on Nvidia cards? " It maps some part of GPU memory into your applications address space. This is not like regular system memory. " Doesn't it have to map a part of the GPU memory into system memory?

Comment: "In fact reading from a mapped buffer will have quite bad performance" I'm aware of this, doesn't SSE 4.1 streaming loads solve this problem, since it allows efficient reading from uswc memory?

Comment: Actually for Nvidia cards I must use pinned memory and CUDA memcpy to get around the problem with horrible `glReadPixels` performance on Gerforce Fermi cards.

Comment: @ronag: SSE streaming has absolutely nothing to do with that. because it operates on CPU memory. However GPU memory must be accessed over that bottleneck called PCI-E which is orders of magnitude slower than your CPU memory bus. The recommendation of CUDA stems from the fact that pinning the memory allows the DMA engine work more efficiently. AMD Fusion has the nice advantage that GPU and CPU share the same memory (bus), thus mapped GPU memory does not go through that bottleneck.

Comment: @ronag: And no. mapping GPU memory does not map it into system memory. System memory is your CPU's RAM. Memory mapping is a catch all term for when non-RAM resources are mapped into a process' address space. Memory mapped resources actually are not even required to be backed by memory at all. The term memory mapping is a bit misleading, it should be called address space mapping.

Comment: Won't `GL_STREAM_READ` buffers most likely already reside in system memory? And isn't it also the same with `GL_STREAM_DRAW`, which effectively means "address mapping" system memory, not video memory?  I did some test with `GL_STREAM_DRAW` buffers, and as expected a memcpy from such a buffer is VERY slow, however it was a few orders of magnitude faster with streaming loads. Doesn't that conflict with your description? My point is that the buffer that is "unmapped" alrdy resides in system memory, and I would like to keep that memory allocated.

Comment: @ronag: The OpenGL driver will most likely **copy** the contents from GPU memory to system memory and then map that piece of memory to your process. It will also install a page fault handler that handles writes to that memory segment. The thing is: You should never make assumptions about the properties of memory mapped regions of non-system-memory resources, like OpenGL buffers, most importantly you should not mistake them for storage for your own process. Use regular memory for that!

Comment: The contents will never originate from the GPU. I'm mostly interested in host to device transfers. I always orphan the buffer before mapping it. With ´GL_STREAM_DRAW´ I would guess that the mapped memory always resides in system-memory. But maybe, as I think you say, I cannot make that assumption? Either way it doesn't change the fact that OpenGL deallocates the memory after "unmap", even if I would like to avoid that.

Comment: In the case of STREAM_READ data originate on the GPU. What happens behind the scenes of glUnmapBuffer is completely undefined and open to the implementation.